# Animação zoomIn fica piscando com mouseenter

Tags: javascript, html, css-hover, animate.css, eventos-do-mouse

Estou usando animate.css pra dar zoom em uma imagem. A ideia é que a animação funcione apenas com o hover/mouseenter, ou seja, quando o usuário passar o mouse em cima dela. Quando utilizo qualquer outra animação senão a zoomIn, funciona normalmente; entretanto, com o código abaixo, apesar do zoom funcionar, a imagem fica piscando quando passo o mouse em determinados lugares. Se eu tiro o .mouseout, o evento só ocorre uma vez. O que fazer para resolver?

```
<img src="imagens/icone.png" class="hover" />

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.hover').mouseenter(function() {
                var mv = $(this);
                mv.addClass('animated zoomIn');
            });
            $('.hover').mouseout(function(){
              var mv = $(this);
              mv.removeClass('animated zoomIn');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Olá Rafaela, isso acontece por que quando a classe zoomIn é adicionada a imagem é redimensionada de scale(0) para scale(1). Nessa transformação, a imagem fica tão pequena que o mouse sai de cima dela. Na verdade a imagem que sai de cima do mouse. Então o segundo evento de mouseout é disparado, fazendo com que a imagem volte ao scale(1) novamente. Dai ao encostar no mouse, é disparado a primeira função e isso fica num loop infinito.

Estou tentando pensar numa solução pra você.

Comment: entendi. Faz todo o sentido, já que só não funciona ESSA animação e com o hover. Outras animações e outros meios de fazer ela funcionar (clique e scroll, por exemplo), funcionam normalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como tinha comentado, este erro estava acontecendo pelo seguinte:

Quando a classe `zoomIn` é adicionada, ela altera as propriedades do elemento como `scale`, que **vai do 0 ao 1**. É isso que faz a animação ocorrer.

Só que como você está ouvindo 2 eventos, um de `mouseenter` e um de `mouseleave`, o handler de `mouseenter` é executado no momento que o usuário passa o mouse.
Mas como o `scale` é diminuido pra 0, a imagem automaticamente sai de baixo do mouse e dispara o handler de `mouseleave`. Esse `handler` por sua vez, tira a classe `zoomIn`.

Esses acontecimentos ficam se repetindo sem parar é por isso que você vê a imagem piscando.

Uma solução é a seguinte:

```
$('.hover').mouseenter(function() {
    var mv = $(this);
    mv.addClass('animated zoomIn').one("mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", function(){
      mv.removeClass('animated zoomIn');
    });
});
```

Na [documentação](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/) é explicado que o método `one()` do JQuery é muito útil quando se quer ao menos executar uma vez um `handler` para uma função e é o que você precisa. Você precisa que o `zoomIn` seja executado pelo menos uma vez antes de poder remove-lo.

Pode ver o funcionamento [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/416215/).

Espero que isso resolva, seu problema.

Abraços.

Comment: deu certo! muito obrigada

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do Andrew é perfeita, realmente resolve o problema, deixo uma alternativa aqui caso opte pela não necessidade de se utilizar uma biblioteca inteira com efeitos que podem ser realizados facilmente **(até com implementações mais visuais)** apenas com **CSS**.

```css
img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  animation-name: imgAnime;
  animation-duration: 1.2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes imgAnime {
  0% { 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  25% {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  50% {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    opacity: 0.6;
 }
  75% {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  100% {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1028674/pexels-photo-1028674.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=apple-black-braided-1028674.jpg&fm=jpg" class="hover" width="200" height="200"/>
```

Comment: Jovem vc viu o que acontece ao colocar o mouse na borda direita ou na borda de baixo da sua imagem. Sua animação está bem bugada...

Comment: Apenas implementei algumas propriedades css, para demonstrar como é mais flexível fazer com css. Realmente não havia percebido o problema na borda, mais algum bug?

Comment: Se o autor veio tentando resolver um bug na animação, não seria legal responder com uma opção que tb está buggada não concorda? Eu tb acho que o ideal seria fazer só com CSS a não ser que ela já tenha jQuery no projeto etc. No caso da sua animação está bugada acredito que é pela forma que vc montou tudo. Se o hover for em uma div que tenha a imagem dentro vc deve conseguir resolver o bug. Se não conseguir, abre um Pergunta que eu ou outro usuário te ajuda a resolver.

Comment: Testei com a img dentro da div primeiramente, mas, quis manter o html dela já que a pegunta tem mais haver com o problema do jQuery, que foi resolvido na resposta do Andrew.